# Can you consistently add axioms about the Busy Beaver function to ZF?

Tags: lo.logic, computer-science

Consider a Turing Machine with $N$ states which checks all theorems of ZF and halts upon finding a contradiction. If ZF were consistent and could prove the value of $BusyBeaver(N)$, then it would be able to prove its own consistency, which Gödel proved impossible; so either ZF is inconsistent or the value of $BB(N)$ is independent of ZF.

But what if we add to ZF an extra axiom K, which specifies the exact (true) value for $BB(k)$ for some large $k$? If ZF is consistent (edit: and sound), then ZFK is consistent (else a contradiction in ZFK would be a proof in ZF of ~K). Now assume that there is a Turing machine with $k$ states or fewer which checks all theorems of ZFK. If it halts, then ZFK is inconsistent, so ZF is inconsistent or unsound. If it doesn't halt after $BB(k)$ steps, then it has proved the consistency of ZFK, which is impossible by Gödel.

It seems like I've shown that either ZF is inconsistent or unsound or that there is no such $k$-state Turing machine which proves the theorems of ZFK. But it seems obvious that for sufficiently large $k$, there are such Turing Machines, since all they need to do is symbolic manipulation of finite axioms. What's going on?

Comment: Your claim that if ZF is consistent, then so is ZFK amounts to a soundness assumption on ZF, that we can add true arithmetic assertions to it consistently. But this is an assumption going beyond ZF.

Comment: What does it mean for a Turing machine to "prove all theorems of ZFK"? Do you mean that it enumerates them one after the other? If so, then of course this machine never halts. I have trouble making sense of this part of your argument. And what does it mean for a Turing machine to "prove its own consistency"? Or are you referring to the theory in that remark, or what?

Comment: Sorry, you're right Joel. I meant that it checks all theorems, and halts if it finds an inconsistency; also that if it doesn't halt, it proves the consistency of ZFK.

Comment: BTW: $k < 8000$ by Yedidia and Aaronson, https://www.scottaaronson.com/busybeaver.pdf

Comment: @EricTowers, that's a factor of 4 larger than it needs to be: https://github.com/sorear/metamath-turing-machines

Comment: Also note that if $k \ge 64$ you potentially have a proof of the non-existence of rank-into-rank cardinals (or the inconsistency of rank-into-rank cardinals with ZFK): http://cheddarmonk.org/papers/laver.pdf

Comment: Isn't the answer to the question that there is no $k$-state Turing Machine **with a blank tape** which proves theorems in ZFK, because the value of $BB(k)$ is so large that it cannot be encoded within any of the finitely many $k$-state machines using a blank tape?  [If you don't use a blank tape, then you don't know anything about stopping times for such a program.]

Answer (score 17):

Let $b_k$ be the assertion that the busy beaver function at $k$ has the value that it actually has, that is, the value it has in the standard natural numbers of the meta-theory. We know that not all of these statements are provable in ZF, if ZF is consistent, since if they were then we would be able to compute the values of the busy beaver function by searching for such proofs.

**Theorem.** The following are equivalent.

1. The theory $\text{ZF}+b_k$ is consistent, for any particular $k$.
2. The theory $\text{ZF}+b_{k_0}+\cdots+b_{k_n}$ is consistent, for any finite list of numbers $k_0,\ldots,k_n$.
3. ZF is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound.

A theory is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound, if any $\Sigma^0_1$ statement that the theory proves is actually true. If ZF is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound, then any true $\Pi^0_1$ sentences must be consistent with ZF, for otherwise we would be able to prove the negation, which would be a false $\Sigma^0_1$-statement, contrary to soundness.

**Proof.** ($3\to 2$) Assume ZF is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound. It already proves all the true $\Sigma^0_1$ assertions about particular machines halting. The extra assertions of the various $b_k$ are $\Pi^0_1$ assertions that no additional Turing machines of the given size halt at some later point. By soundness, these are consistent with ZF, as desired.

($2\to 1$) Immediate.

($1\to 3$) Suppose that we can consistently add any statements $b_k$ to ZF. Suppose that ZF proves some assertion $\exists n\, \varphi(n)$, where $\varphi(n)$ is $\Delta^0_0$. Consider the program $e$ that embarks on a search to find such an $n$. This program uses $k$ states for some $k$, and so if there is such an $n$, then ZF would prove that it would have to stop before the busy beaver value $BB(k)$, since otherwise we would violate the definition of $BB(k)$. Thus, if $ZF+b_k$ is consistent, ZF would prove that there is such an $n$ below the actual value of $BB(k)$. So the $\Sigma^0_1$ statement was true, and therefore ZF was $\Sigma^0_1$-sound, as desired.
$\Box$

Meanwhile, let me point out that it is relatively consistent with ZF that ZF is not $\Sigma^0_1$-sound. For example, in any model of ZF in which $\neg\text{Con}(ZF)$, then obviously ZF will be proving false $\Sigma^0_1$ statements in the model. So if ZF is consistent, then so is ZF plus the assertion that ZF is not $\Sigma^0_1$-sound.

Comment: Perhaps this isnt' a place to ask, but I've had a couple of students ask me what "actually true" means if truth depends on the model (that would usually be a smart student who learned about models). How do you answer such a question, from a pedagogical point of view?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I believe that is a deep philosophical question. But one can begin to answer by making the theory/meta-theory distinction: when we use a theory, we are typically committed to certain mathematical assertions in the meta-theory. Often, a very weak meta-theory suffices, but one can also work in a strong meta-theory. For example, the model theorists typically undertake model theory in ZFC itself, and in this case one can view the meta-theory as ZFC, even when one analyzes ZFC as an object theory. But it is important to recognize that these two theories are not the same.

Comment: To assert that a particular mathematical statement is "actually true" is to make the assertion in the meta-theory as opposed to the object theory, and questions of soundness are always about the interaction of this kind of truth. Matters get philosophically complicated, however, when you realize that there are many different meta-theories you might use, or indeed an entire hiearchy of theories, each of which might serve as a meta-theoretic context for the object theories it has. In this case, claims of "actually true" should be understood as reletive to a particular meta-theoretic context.

Comment: Part of my multiverse pluralist perspective is that there is no one absolute meta-theoretic context. Every one of the mathematical universes provides a meta-theoretic context for the object theories and models available in it.

Comment: The next question then is: how do we know which meta-theory we're in? Even worse, how do we know that you and I are in the same meta-theory? *Are we?*

Comment: Well, the answer of course is that we don't and we can't. If you are making an argument that relies on meta-theoretic assumptions, then it is better for you to make those assumptions explicit.

Comment: If I push this a little further, so it might be tha case that you and I will discover different values of $b_{42}$?

Comment: Well, we already know that it is consistent even with strong theories that some $b_k$ have different values (or else the particular values couldn't be independent). So we already know how to make different meta-theories like that.

Comment: I am not asking whether it's possible to arrange different values of $b_k$ but whether the two of us might actually discover different values. (Of course, my evil plan is to coax you into admitting that logic is an experimental science.)

Comment: My view is that every meta-theory is just an object theory for a still higher meta-theory. I wouldn't know what it means to "discover" a $\Pi^0_1$ assertion in the meta theory, since it isn't like we can stumble upon an example, except to find a proof of it from one's other meta-theoretic assumptions, which is just what I am talking about.

Comment: I'm confused by the first sentence of this answer.  Why work with the standard natural numbers of the meta-theory, instead of the standard natural numbers of the theory itself?  Or why not the standard natural numbers of the meta-meta-theory?

Comment: @PaceNielsen If ZF doesn't settle the value of $BB(42)$, then what do you mean by using the standard natural numbes of the theory itself? It is a theory, after all, rather than a model.  Soundness only makes sense when comparing the assertions proved by a theory with what is true in the meta-theory or in the background context, however one wants to talk about it.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins That's precisely my question back to you, *mutatis mutandis*.  If the meta-theory doesn't settle the value of $BB(42)$, then what do you mean by using the standard natural numbers of the meta-theory?   Are you assuming some strong conditions on the meta-theory, like it decides all values of the busy beaver function?  (If so, doesn't that, in itself, answer the OP's question?)

Comment: We don't normally expect the meta theory to be complete, and indeed, a weak meta theory will not typically settle the value of $BB(k)$ for numerous $k$. However, even a very weak meta-theory will prove that there is a value of $BB(k)$; for example, this is provable in PA and much less. So one can take $BB(k)$ to define a number, whatever it is, in the meta theory, and this provides one with a way of referring to the actual value of $BB(k)$ in the meta-theory, for the purpose of adding the statement $b_k$ as an axiom to the object theory ZF+$b_k$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Let's make this concrete.  Suppose the base theory is ZFC and the meta-theory is PA.  Why does defining $BB(k)$ to be the number that PA proves exists work better than defining $BB(k)$ to be the number that ZFC proves exists?  Why work in the meta-theory, when you can make that part work in the base theory?  [In other words, both theories "prove that there is a value of $BB(k)$", so why use the the existential quantity proven to exist in the meta-theory?  It's a weaker theory.]

Comment: Perhaps neither PA nor ZFC prove that any particular concretely representable number is $BB(k)$, but PA proves "there is a value for BB(k)", and in the meta theory, it is good enough to have such a non-concretely represented number in order to speak of the expression $b_k$ there. That is, in the meta-theory PA we can refer to $b_k$ without having a concrete value for $BB(k)$.

Comment: I think I got it now.  The sentence $b_k$ is asserting equality between the value the base theory gives to $BB(k)$ and the value the meta-theory gives to $BB(k)$. (So even though both numbers might not be concretely representable, by asserting they are equal we get a stronger statement.)  We could then iterate this process and get even stronger statements by working in a meta-meta-theory, etc...

Comment: If I'm right about what $b_k$ means, how does that address Richard's question?  If we were "magically" given a concrete number $N$ such that $BB(2000)=N$, and added that statement to the base theory, would that imply $b_{2000}$?  I don't see why it would, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The sentence $b_k$ asserts the concrete value for $BB(k)$ which is true in the meta-theoretic context, even if the axioms you have adopted in the meta-theory don't determine which particular concrete value that is, but only prove that there is such a value. If you know the de re/de dicto distinction, then $b_k$ asserts the value de re, but we describe that value in the meta-theory de dicto.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins : I'm confused about one point. To conclude that not all the $b_k$ are provable in ZF, don't we need to assume that ZF is $\Sigma^0_1$-sound, not just that ZF is consistent?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I wasn't previously aware of the de re/de dicto distinction, so thank you.  I'm still missing why your response answers my question.  Perhaps this is centered around the word "concrete" which you seem to be using in a way different than I.  Let's say $N$ is given to us as a natural number written as a finite string using the standard binary representation.  Why would assuming $BB(2000)=N$ imply $b_k$?  [Note: If $N$ is the value of $BB(2000)$, then $N$ equals the de dicto value asserted by $b_k$.  But that doesn't necessarily imply we can prove it, does it?]

Answer (score 3):

Pick your $k$ so that you're adding an axiom to ZF which contains a number $N$ that you've pulled out of somewhere, that purports that $BB(k)=N$.  That equality (by supposition) happens to be *true*, but since it can't be proved by normal means, the best you can say about your new axiom is that it purports something.  Now there are potentially three classes of $k$-state Turing machines:

Class 1: those that halt in $\le N$ steps
Class 2: those that eventually halt, but in more than $N$ steps.
Class 3: those that never halt.

Your new axiom claims, simply, that class 2 is empty.  That is, if you run all the $k$-state TM's for up to $N$ steps, at least one machine will halt on exactly the $N$th step, and those which haven't halted by then will never halt.

In other words, the new axiom asserts a whole lot of otherwise undecidable $\Pi^0_1$ sentences that various TM's don't halt.

For large enough $k$, one of those machines will be a machine that searches for a proof in ZFC that 1=0.

In other words, the new axiom asserts (among other things), CON(ZFC).  So yes, if you add an axiom asserting CON(ZFC), then $\vdash$CON(ZFC) which is no big surprise.  This still works if your new axiom has given the wrong value of $N$, since that means you have an inconsistent theory, and inconsistent theories prove anything.  Since the halting problem is undecidable, if you actually *do* have the right value of $N$, you can never prove it, because of all the machines that it asserts never halt, but that (as far as you can tell) eventually might halt if you run them long enough.

Comment: That makes sense, but for large enough k, will one of those machines also be a machine that searches for a proof in ZFK that 1=0?

Comment: @RichardNgo You have defined ZFK to depend on $k$. For any fixed $k$, for large enough $k'$, one of the machines will be a machine that searches for contradictions in $ZFK_k$. But we can never take $k'=k$ by Godel's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your argument in fact proves that there is no a Turing machine with $k$ states which can check all theorems of ZFK:

axioms of ZF can be enumerated by a very simple Turing machine $M_1$. But to describe the extra axiom K (which is of the form $BB(k)=\overline{n}$) we needs to describe the number $n$  and it needs at least a Turing machine $M_2$ with $k$ states (by the definition of $BB$ function). So if we combine the Turing machines $M_1$ and $M_2$ and write a Turing machine $M_3$ which enumerate all axioms of ZFK and then check all its theorems, it seems reasonable that this machine need more than $k$ states. This is the fact that your argument proves:

**Theoerm**. (assuming that ZF is $\Sigma_1$-sound) for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, any Turing machine which checks all theorems of ZFK(which is ZF+$BB(k)=\overline{n}$, where $n$ is the true value of $BB(k)$) has at least $k+1$ states.